# Empty row in between action bar and fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I am working on a fragment but realized that there is an empty row in between my action bar and content in the emulator. This space cannot be edited out. My fragment also only starts from the end of this space. Since, the size of the row is similar to that of a an action bar, I believe it could have occurred when I made changes to my action bar settings. Also my XML file and emulator are both for Pixel 2 so there shouldn't be any issues with the sizing.

Image of the issue:

[image: Image of the issue:]

Fragment code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_explore"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
    tools:context=".ui.explore.ExploreFragment">


    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <GridLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:columnCount="5"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:rowCount="2"
                        android:padding="10dp">



                        <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/imageButton24"
                            android:layout_width="100dp"
                            android:layout_height="100dp"
                            android:background="@null"
                            android:src="@drawable/logo_lenovo" />




                    </GridLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>

 

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <GridLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:columnCount="2"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingBottom="140dp"
                    android:rowCount="3">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/imageButton17"
                        android:layout_width="175dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon_keyboards" />



                </GridLayout>

            </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Manifest Code (implemented no action bar for activities)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ireview">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".ui.search.SearchViewModel" />
        <activity
            android:name=".NavigationActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_navigation" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Authentication.LogInPage"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Authentication.SignUpPage"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Authentication.LogInMenu"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Authentication.SignUpMenu"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Authentication.MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: do you want to remove the actio bar or do you want to remove the whitespace between the action bar and the fragment?

Comment: the white space between the action bar and the fragment

Comment: could you please add the code where you add the fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was a rather silly one. I had top-padding set for a fragment, hence the gap. Removing it god rid of the gap.